# How to make every letter of word into caps but not for letter "of", "and", "it", "for"?

Tags: vba, excel

For example "director of medicine" and I want it as "Director of Medicine not "Director Of Medicine" . I do not want letter "of" to be capitalise. Please help

Comment: We aren't psychics, as much as we want to be. You give no context or code, and there's no question or detail. It's unclear. We can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

The following VBA code would be a good start.

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Function ProperIsh(inputString As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim currWord As String
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim wordPos As Integer

    ' List of words to revert to lower-case '

    Dim lowerWords As Variant
    lowerWords = Array("Of", "And", "It", "For", "Am", "The")

    ' Get proper-cased string with spaces on either end '

    result = " " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(inputString) & " "

    ' Process each word to revert to lower-case '

    For idx = 1 To UBound(lowerWords)
        ' Revert every one of that word with spaces on either side '

        currWord = " " & lowerWords(idx) & " "
        wordPos = InStr(result, currWord)
        While wordPos > 0
           result = Left(result, wordPos - 1) & LCase(currWord) & Mid(result, wordPos + Len(currWord))
           wordPos = InStr(result, currWord)
        Wend
    Next

    ' Get rid of the spaces at the end '

    ProperIsh = Mid(result, 2, Len(result) - 2)
End Function
```

And some test code for it:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox (ProperIsh("HELLO I AM THE LAW and i am the lower case law of everything"))
End Sub
```

What it does is to proper-case every word (upper-case first letter, everything else lower-case) then systematically revert any of the special words back to all lower-case.

It presupposes that space is the only separator but could be made more adaptable if that's the case.

The test code generates a message box with the expected output:

```
Hello I am the Law and I am the Lower Case Law of Everything
```

In order to use it in your expression, treat it as any other user defined function, such as with:

```
=ProperIsh(A1)
```

You can see it in operation with the following "screenshot" where column B uses the formula shown above:

```
             A                          B
1   director of medicine       Director of Medicine 
2   I am the law               I am the Law 
3   Let slip the dogs of war   Let Slip the Dogs of War
```

Comment: When using -ish as a suffix there's no need to capitalise it ;D

Answer (score 0):

I used [Rules for Capitalization in Titles of Articles](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html) as a reference to create a capitalization exceptions list.

`Function TitleCase` uses `WorksheetFunction.ProperCase` to preproccess the text.  For this reason, I put in an exception for contractions because `WorksheetFunction.ProperCase` improperly capitalizes them.

The first word in each sentence and the first word after a double quotation mark will remain capitalized. Punctuation marks are also handled properly.

```
Function TitleCase(text As String) As String
    Dim doc
    Dim sentence, word, w
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim arrLowerCaseWords

    arrLowerCaseWords = Array("a", "an", "and", "as", "at", "but", "by", "for", "in", "of", "on", "or", "the", "to", "up", "nor", "it", "am", "is")

    text = WorksheetFunction.Proper(text)

    Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
    doc.Range.text = text

    For Each sentence In doc.Sentences
        For i = 2 To sentence.Words.Count
            If sentence.Words.Item(i - 1) <> """" Then
                Set w = sentence.Words.Item(i)
                For Each word In arrLowerCaseWords
                    If LCase(Trim(w)) = word Then
                        w.text = LCase(w.text)
                    End If

                    j = InStr(w.text, "'")

                    If j Then w.text = Left(w.text, j) & LCase(Right(w.text, Len(w.text) - j))

                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

    TitleCase = doc.Range.text

    doc.Close False
    Set doc = Nothing
End Function
```