# Proper Case with extra rules in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have used vba for Proper Case in Excel but I need to add an exception rule for it to save much manual editing. I need the first letter after "-" to also be Capitalized, example is:
"michael-jordan" becomes "Michael-jordan" now when I run my script.
I need "michael-jordan" to become "Michael-Jordan".

Here is my code:
I also have an exception for "von", "af" and "de" in my code.

```
Sub ProperCase()

Dim rng As Range

'Use special cells so as not to overwrite formula.
For Each rng In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
    Select Case rng.Value
        Case "von", "af", "de"
            rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase)
        Case Else
            'StrConv is the VBA version of Proper.
            rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbProperCase)
    End Select
Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbProperCase)
```

use

```
rng.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(rng.Value)
```

Though this does not consider cases like `don't doesn't` as mentioned by Thomas Inzina.

Comment: Good thinking! Elegant!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a copy of my answer from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559887/how-to-make-every-letter-of-word-into-caps-but-not-for-letter-of-and-it/38562949#38562949). It should work nicely for you.

I used [Rules for Capitalization in Titles of Articles](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html) as a reference to create a capitalization exceptions list.

`Function TitleCase` uses `WorksheetFunction.ProperCase` to preproccess the text.  For this reason, I put in an exception for contractions because `WorksheetFunction.ProperCase` improperly capitalizes them.

The first word in each sentence and the first word after a double quotation mark will remain capitalized. Punctuation marks are also handled properly.

```
Function TitleCase(text As String) As String
    Dim doc
    Dim sentence, word, w
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim arrLowerCaseWords

    arrLowerCaseWords = Array("a", "an", "and", "as", "at", "but", "by", "for", "in", "of", "on", "or", "the", "to", "up", "nor", "it", "am", "is")

    text = WorksheetFunction.Proper(text)

    Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
    doc.Range.text = text

    For Each sentence In doc.Sentences
        For i = 2 To sentence.Words.Count
            If sentence.Words.Item(i - 1) <> """" Then
                Set w = sentence.Words.Item(i)
                For Each word In arrLowerCaseWords
                    If LCase(Trim(w)) = word Then
                        w.text = LCase(w.text)
                    End If

                    j = InStr(w.text, "'")

                    If j Then w.text = Left(w.text, j) & LCase(Right(w.text, Len(w.text) - j))

                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

    TitleCase = doc.Range.text

    doc.Close False
    Set doc = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little VBA Function using Split wich should do the desired work:

```
Function properCase(str As String) As String

Dim splitStr() As String

splitStr = Split(str, "-")

Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(splitStr) To UBound(splitStr) Step 1

    splitStr(i) = UCase(Left(splitStr(i), 1)) & Right(splitStr(i), Len(splitStr(i)) - 1)
Next i

properCase = Join(splitStr, "-")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to do this in VBA when it's easily done on the worksheet?

```
=PROPER("michael-jordan")
```

returns `Michael-Jordan` as required

Comment: Yes, since this is only one step in a series of steps in the process and most importantly I need exceptions, also I dont want to change or add columns to the database

Comment: I don't like Proper because it doesn't handle apostrophes correctly. e.g.  `WorksheetFunction.Proper(" don't doesn't ")` outpts ` Don'T Doesn'T `.