# How to capitalize first letter after opening bracket and apply on entire worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am using the following VBA code to convert text to Proper case:

```
Sub Proper()
Dim ws As Object
Dim LCell As Range

'Move through each sheet in your spreadsheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

   'Convert all constants and text values to proper case
    For Each LCell In Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues)
       LCell.Formula = StrConv(LCell.Formula, vbProperCase)
    Next

Next ws
End Sub
```

I need to add to the function. 
After an opening bracket, the first letter should be capitalized.

Here is an example:
*google (android)* should become *Google (Android)*.

Is there a way to edit the above code to add this rule, or do I have to loop each character through an If condition?

Comment: Check out my answer to [Proper Case with extra rules in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569861/proper-case-with-extra-rules-in-excel/39569977#39569977)

Comment: @ThomasInzina thanks that certainly helped explain a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Worksheet function instead:

```
Sub Proper()
Dim ws As Object
Dim LCell As Range

'Move through each sheet in your spreadsheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

 '  Convert all constants and text values to proper case
    For Each LCell In Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues)
       LCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(LCell)
    Next

Next ws
End Sub
```