# Excel VBA performance of function using Proper on specific range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Here is a function that checks the cells in column B and C and applies the `Proper` function per a specific test.

```
Sub proper_function()

    Dim rng, cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("B:B", "C:C")

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not cell.HasFormula Then
            cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

This takes a long time to process and has crashed Excel on occasions.

I'd rather it look through the cells with text rather than the whole column, I think I need to modify the for loop slightly but can't get it to work, what is the best way to write this so it doesn't slow down the sheet?

Thanks

Comment: How many rows of data do you have?

Comment: We need to know what your sheet looks like. You want the loop to break once you've hit the end of the data, but you have not given us a way to determine where that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change (not tested):

```
Sub proper_function()

Dim rng as Range
Dim cell As Variant

Set rng = Range("B:B", "C:C")
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range(rng.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)    
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
Next cell

End Sub
```

But I would also find the last row, as suggested in another answer, and set `rng`only to the used range. Also, as Thomas pointed out, `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `.Calculation` are important to add if you have volatile functions or functions with the constant cells as precedents. That might be key to boosting your speed as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. Was curious to see if I could use this same code for the Lower function just by changing Proper to Lower but it didn't work?

Comment: @Pete Change `WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
` to `LCase(cell.Value)` (or `UCase` for upper case). Also, if my code solved your issue please mark with green checkmark. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a fan of the WorksheetFunction `Proper` because it doesn't capitalize contractions properly (e.g.  `can't, doesn't, I'll` become `Can'T, Doesn'T, I'Ll`).  My answer to [Proper Case with extra rules in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569861/proper-case-with-extra-rules-in-excel/39569977#39569977) has my own function `TitleCase` that correctly capitalizes contractions.

The `Target` range only contains non blank cells that have constant values (no formula)

```
Set Target = Intersect(.Range("B:C"), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

Turning off `ScreenUpdating` and `Calculation` greatly improves performance.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

---

```
Sub proper_function()
    Dim Target As Range, cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Target = Intersect(.Range("B:C"), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With


    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        For Each cell In Target
            If Not cell.HasFormula Then
                cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
            End If
        Next cell
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps I am not fully understanding but why do you test `If Not cell.HasFormula` if Range `Target` is only `xlCellTypeConstants`?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to run into problems if you try to loop through every cell in a .xlsx or .xlsm file, because they have 1,048,576 rows, and you're doing that twice! It's going to cause slowdown, whatever you do.

Rather than using a blanket range of B:B and C:C, you can limit it to the range that might have data in it. Without seeing your sheet, I can't say for sure the best way to do that, but in general terms try something like this:

```
Sub Properiser()
    Dim rngAll As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngLast As Long

    lngLast = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > lngLast Then 
        lngLast = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    Set rngAll = Range("B1", "C" & lngLast)

    For Each rngCell In rngAll
        If Not rngCell.HasFormula Then
            rngCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

This will find the last used row in column B, then in column C, and use whichever is larger as the end point of the range.

There are other methods we could use, like using the UsedRange property to find how many rows and columns have actually been used in the file, but without seeing your data it's hard to say whether one of those might work better for you or not.

EDITED TO EXPAND:

Now, you mentioned that you'd rather have the process only look at cells that contain text; there's a couple of ways we could do that.

**Option 1:** Check for empty cells

If you suspect you're bouncing through a lot of empty cells, you can simply check for cell contents in your If condition.

```
if len(rngCell.value) <> 0 then
   'Function
end if
```

**Option 2:** Check for non-text values

Unfortunately we don't have a simple, single function that can check for alphanumeric text; we need to go by a process of elimination. Thus:

```
if len(rngCell.value) <> 0 then
    if isnumeric(rngcell.value) = False AND _
       iserror(rngcell.value) = false then
        'Assume it's text and perform our function
    End if
End if
```

...etc. You can stack as many checks as you need to in the IF loop.