# vba subroutine works on one sheet but not another

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to clean names on two separate sheets "Alpha Roster" and "Paid".  Alpha Roster is updated by other people and Paid is my master tracker of who has paid.  I have a function called "MakeProper" that works fairly well at making corrections on Alpha Roster but for some reason does not make any corrections to Paid.  Both sheets are set up the same.

```
Sub CleanUpPaid()

    Sheets("Paid").Activate
    Sheets("Paid").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    MakeProper

End Sub

Sub MakeProper()
  Dim rngSrc As Range
  Dim lMax As Long, lCtr As Long

  Set rngSrc = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveWindow.Selection.Address)
  lMax = rngSrc.Cells.Count

  ' clean up Sponsor's Names
  For lCtr = 3 To lMax
    If Not rngSrc.Cells(lCtr, 1).HasFormula And _
            rngSrc.Cells(lCtr, 1) <> "CMC" Then
        rngSrc.Cells(lCtr, 1) = MakeBetterProper(rngSrc.Cells(lCtr, 1))
    End If

  ' clean up Guest's Names
    If Not rngSrc.Cells(lCtr, 7).HasFormula Then
        rngSrc.Cells(lCtr, 7) = MakeBetterProper(rngSrc.Cells(lCtr, 7))
    End If

  Next lCtr
  'MsgBox ("Make Proper " & ActiveSheet.Name)
End Sub

Function MakeBetterProper(ByVal ref As Range) As String
  Dim vaArray As Variant
  Dim c As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim J As Integer
  Dim vaLCase As Variant
  Dim str As String

  ' Array contains terms that should be lower case
  vaLCase = Array("CMC", "II", "II,", "III", "III,")

  ref.Replace what:=",", Replacement:=", "
  ref.Replace what:=",  ", Replacement:=", "
  ref.Replace what:="-", Replacement:=" - "
  c = StrConv(ref, 3)

  'split the words into an array
  vaArray = Split(c, " ")

  For i = (LBound(vaArray) + 1) To UBound(vaArray)
    For J = LBound(vaLCase) To UBound(vaLCase)
        ' compare each word in the cell against the
        ' list of words to remain lowercase. If the
        ' Upper versions match then replace the
        ' cell word with the lowercase version.
        If UCase(vaArray(i)) = UCase(vaLCase(J)) Then
            vaArray(i) = vaLCase(J)
        End If
    Next J
  Next i

' rebuild the sentence
  str = ""
  For i = LBound(vaArray) To UBound(vaArray)
    str = str & " " & vaArray(i)
    str = Replace(str, " - ", "-")
    str = Replace(str, "J'q", "J'Q")
    str = Replace(str, "Jr", "Jr.")
    str = Replace(str, "Jr..", "Jr.")
    str = Replace(str, "(Jr.)", "Jr.")
    str = Replace(str, "Sr", "Sr.")
    str = Replace(str, "Sr..", "Sr.")
  Next i

  MakeBetterProper = Trim(str)

End Function
```

I read up on the difference between select and activate.  As you can see, in CleanUpPaid, I try a couple different ways to make the Paid sheet the active sheet but nothing appears to occur on the sheet like it does in Alpha Roster.

Comment: please don't update your _question_ to post an _answer_.  If you want to post what you ended up with, post it _as_ an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are only processing one cell on the `Worksheets("Paid")` and that is `Range("A2")`.  You can eleiminate `Set rngSrc = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveWindow.Selection.Address)` and just use `Selection` it is returning a range object.

Assuming that you want to process the cells in columns A and G.  I'm using my function `TitleCase` to correct the capitalization but you can substitute `MakeBetterProper` if you would like.

---

```
Sub FixNames()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("Alpha Roster", "Paid"))
        With ws
            For Each c In Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)

                If Not c.HasFormula And c.Value <> "CMC" Then c.Value = TitleCase(c.text)

            Next

            For Each c In Intersect(.Columns(7), .UsedRange)

                If Not c.HasFormula Then c.Value = TitleCase(c.text)

            Next

        End With

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

My answer to [How to make every letter of word into caps but not for letter “of”, “and”, “it”, “for” ?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559887/how-to-make-every-letter-of-word-into-caps-but-not-for-letter-of-and-it/38562949#38562949) will correct the capitalization for you.

I used [Rules for Capitalization in Titles of Articles](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html) as a reference to create a capitalization exceptions list.

`Function TitleCase` uses `WorksheetFunction.ProperCase` to preproccess the text.  For this reason, I put in an exception for contractions because `WorksheetFunction.ProperCase` improperly capitalizes them.

The first word in each sentence and the first word after a double quotation mark will remain capitalized. Punctuation marks are also handled properly.

---

```
Function TitleCase(text As String) As String
    Dim doc
    Dim sentence, word, w
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim arrLowerCaseWords

    arrLowerCaseWords = Array("a", "an", "and", "as", "at", "but", "by", "for", "in", "of", "on", "or", "the", "to", "up", "nor", "it", "am", "is")

    text = WorksheetFunction.Proper(text)

    Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
    doc.Range.text = text

    For Each sentence In doc.Sentences
        For i = 2 To sentence.Words.Count
            If sentence.Words.Item(i - 1) <> """" Then
                Set w = sentence.Words.Item(i)
                For Each word In arrLowerCaseWords
                    If LCase(Trim(w)) = word Then
                        w.text = LCase(w.text)
                    End If

                    j = InStr(w.text, "'")

                    If j Then w.text = Left(w.text, j) & LCase(Right(w.text, Len(w.text) - j))

                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

    TitleCase = doc.Range.text

    doc.Close False
    Set doc = Nothing
End Function
```